# Disable Touch Hold in Unity3d

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, touch

i'm using a script so when user touches the screen player jumps in the air
but the problem is when user holds the touch the player stuck in the air and never falls down
how can i disable touch hold so when user only touches once player jumps once ?

```
Rigidbody2D Rigid;
public float UpForce;
public float RightSpeed;

void Start()
{
    Rigid = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D> ();
}

void Update()
{
    transform.Translate (Vector2.right * Time.deltaTime * RightSpeed);
}

void FixedUpdate()
{
    foreach (Touch touch in Input.touches)
    {
        Rigid.AddForce (Vector2.up * UpForce);
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add check for the touch phase. In this case, [`TouchPhase.Began`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/TouchPhase.Began.html) is appropriate since it will jump when user touches the screen. If you want it to jump when user releases the touch then use [`TouchPhase.Ended`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/TouchPhase.Ended.html).

```
foreach (Touch touch in Input.touches)
{
    if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Began)
    {
        Rigid.AddForce(Vector2.up * UpForce);
    }
}
```

**Note**:

You should always check for Input event in the `Update()` function not in the `FixedUpdate()` function. I suggest you put that code in the `Update()` function. Your physics code should go in the `FixedUpdate()` function.

Comment: Hi, you have to put that code from my answer in the Update function. I just verified that it works on my device with Unity Remote. Maybe there is something wrong with your Unity Remote. Try it on the device it self.

Comment: Also, to find what's causing this, add ` Debug.Log("Jumped");` on top of  `Rigid.AddForce(Vector2.up * UpForce);` and see if that shows up in the console. If it does then there is a problem with your Rigidbody.

Comment: i got the debug.log jump but the actual jump is not happenning

Comment: thank you programmer i changed the upforce and every thing is ok !
best wishes for you....

Comment: I was gonna say that. Anyways, glad you got it working.